# Let $G$ be a finite group. If $x$ is the unique involution of $G$, then $x \in Z(G)$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. If $x$ is the unique involution of $G$, then $x \in Z(G)$.

My attempt: let $y \in G$ be of even order then $x \in \langle y\rangle$ and $x \in C_G(y)$

If $y$ is of odd order then $|xy|=|x|\times|y|$ and the element $xy$ is of even order. By the previous paragraph we get $x \in C_G(xy)$  i.e $x(xy)=(xy)x$,

yields $xy=yx$   (using cancellation law)

then $x\in C_G(y)$ for every $y\in G$

Finally $x\in Z(G)$

Is my attempt right?

Comment: I cannot follow anything after "If $y$ is of odd order".

Comment: @LostinSpace yes it answers and it's easier than the way I used but is my attempt right or missing some details?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I have added some details I hope it helps

Comment: Every conjugate of $x$ is also an involution, hence equal to $x$, which means that $x$ is in the center.